# What to display in area where event-driven content should appear later

Tags: navigation, menu, bootstrap

I asked a question [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89476/how-to-display-nested-categories-of-data-without-using-nested-menus) looking for design ideas for an alternative to the nested drop-down menus scheme I had come up with.  User mikryz helpfully provided an alternative idea with this mockup:

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out what to display on the left hand side when a user first visits the site and has not selected a "report category" from the top "Reports" drop down menu at the top.

The two ideas I had were to display a vertical bar from top to bottom with the same color as the navigation bar but with nothing in it.  Then populate it upon the event.  I don't like this idea because I don't want a dark background underneath the content (the nav bar color must stay the same).

The other idea I had was to have the content slide in from the left when the user clicks a Report category.  However, I'm still unable to find a way to get it to slide in **underneath** the navbar instead of pushing the navbar to the right as well (I'm using Bootstrap 3).  I know this is a UX forum and not primarily a developers or BS3 forum so I am not holding out hope for help solving this.  Suffice to say I've googled for hours without solution.  SE prevents me from posting a link to the "answered" solutions to this problem that did not help me.

**My question:  What should I display in an area on initial page load that only contains content after a user makes a selection?**

In particular, looking at the graphic above: what should go on the left-hand side when the page loads for a user but before she has chosen a category of content to display there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may suggest a slight change of direction:

The layout you provide in the question (I'll call it the "read screen") is tied to a top-level report category - "Local Catalog Maintenance" in this case. If no top-level category is has been selected by the user, you'd want to show a different view entirely.

Typically this would be a "index screen" of some kind - a list of the top-level categories, which the user can click on to get to the read screen.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'll try to implement this - it sounds like a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1:

Anticipatory design:
I would recommend pushing the user to one of the selections based on the data you get from your users. Which one is the hottest zone.

Suggestion 2:

Matrix Solution: 
You can present the user with the first 2 option he has in your platform.
Blue pill: Results
Red pull: Reports
+ a little description for each.
[image]